# css/js are cached when accessed from outside network

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, browser-cache

This is a sort of curious case to me.

We have a tomcat server running in-house in our organization. We have a deployed an application on the same tomcat server. When I accessed the website the tomcat is serving, all the js/css files are not cached by the browser at all, which means it is returning status code 200 for every request.

But they opened the port for being able to work from home this weekend, and when I accessed the website from my home, surprisingly those css and js are cached (http code 304)

what do you guys think could be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

Could you have different cache settings on your browsers? Such as this IE setting: https://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page

You could also use Firefox + Firebug to take a look at the response header, your particularly interested in the "expires" setting on the cache tab.

Comment: I have been using Firefox 5 with Firebug. So this answer is not valid.

Comment: @Anthony, It would be helpful if you specified this in your question

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will consider next time.